# Actual imported file when I specified an module in node_modules written in Typescript.

Tags: typescript, npm

I made a typescript module(named `moduleA`). I'd like to publish this package and I want to use this from another typescript project.

For the present, I installed 'moduleA' with 'npm install ../moduleA' since this is just a test. 
And These file must be placed like below.

```
B
  node_modules
    moduleA
      dist
        index.ts
```

As you can see, there is a directory `dist` in the root directory of `moduleA`.
I want to import this `index.ts` with typescript like below.
`import A from 'moduleA';`

If there was `index.ts` just inside of moduleA folder, this would work.
And if this was javascript file, I can write this as `main` property of package.json.

However, in this case, I want to use typescript directly and I don't want to put index.ts out of dist folder.

And I don't want to make another index.ts like this.

```
import d from './dist/index';
export default d;
```

Because there is several folders in dist, and I'd like to reference them from project depends on `moduleA`.

Is there good way to specify default typescript file of a package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are good option for typescript to specify in package.json.
The property of "typings" worked fine for me.
This is good reference below.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typings-for-npm-packages.html

When I specified a definition file for this property, that file would be loaded as definition. But, it required for me to remember to use the "main" property also. Cuz, the typings are just a definition to use in compiling time. And instance of the code is in the JavaScript specified in "main" property.